# chat with Poll on C(Poll function with char)

Tags: c, chat

Мне нужно написать чат с использованием POLL. Но в целом не знаю как это делать.

кто-нибудь может подсказать?

Comment: Почему вы на двух языках спрашиваете? Боитесь, что вас не поймут?

Comment: Очевидно, вызов `poll`     на сервере дает вам активный (на который что-то пришло) сокет (в т.ч. присоединение нового участника). Вы читаете данные из него и переписываете их в остальные или добавляете сокет нового участника в набор сокетов для poll. Только не забудьте снабдить пересылаемый текст логином источника (который он должен предоставить, когда коннектится к вашему чат-серверу)